# Rust - Asynchronous call JsFuture in Yew framework

Tags: asynchronous, rust, wasm-bindgen

I have a board game front end application developped with Yew.
During the lifecycle of my application, I got a moment where my MinMax algorithm is searching for the best move to play, and my screen is freezing because I call it as synchronous method.

I want to display a classic message "AI is thinking, please wait..." and call my method asynchronously.

I found example on Github (https://github.com/yewstack/yew/tree/master/examples/futures), and now here is the code :

```rust
/// This is the code from the Github example
async fn fetch_markdown(url: &'static str) -> Result<String, FetchError> {
    info!("fetch_markdown");

    let mut opts = RequestInit::new();
    opts.method("GET");
    opts.mode(RequestMode::Cors);

    let request = Request::new_with_str_and_init(url, &opts)?;

    let window = gloo::utils::window();
    let resp_value = JsFuture::from(window.fetch_with_request(&request)).await?;
    let resp: Response = resp_value.dyn_into().unwrap();

    let text = JsFuture::from(resp.text()?).await?;
    info!("fetch_markdown : text received");
    Ok(text.as_string().unwrap())
}

/// This is my code
async fn ai_async_choose_piece_for_opponent() -> Result<quarto_game::piece::Piece, FetchError> {
    let ai_promise = future_to_promise(async {
        // Create an empty board
        let board = quarto_game::board::Board::create();
        // Create a minmax algo with depth = 2
        let mut minmax = quarto_game::ai::minmax_tree::MinMaxTree::new(2, true);

        // And now this function take a while
        let p = quarto_game::ai::Strategy::choose_piece_for_opponent(&mut minmax, &board);
        Ok(JsValue::from_str(p.as_text().as_str()))
    });

    // Ok now here I have my piece returned by my promise inside JsValue
    let resp_value = JsFuture::from(ai_promise).await?;

    info!("JsFuture::from(ai_promise).await? >> answer {:?}", resp_value);
    let string_piece = resp_value.as_string().unwrap();
    Ok(quarto_game::piece::Piece::from(string_piece.as_str()))
}

/// I skip some code which is not relevant
///...

impl Component for App {
    fn update(&mut self, ctx: &Context<Self>, msg: Self::Message) -> bool {
        match msg {
            Msg::SetDataFetchState(fetch_state) => {
                self.markdown = fetch_state;
                true
            }
            Msg::GetData(data_type) => {
                info!("[Msg::GetData] GetData send futur");
                match data_type {
                    DataType::Markdown => {
                        ctx.link().send_future(async {
                            match fetch_markdown(MARKDOWN_URL).await {
                                Ok(md) => Msg::SetDataFetchState(FetchState::Success(md)),
                                Err(err) => Msg::SetDataFetchState(FetchState::Failed(err)),
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    DataType::AI => {
                        ctx.link().send_future(async {
                            match ai_async_choose_piece_for_opponent().await {
                                Ok(p) => Msg::SetDataFetchState(FetchState::Success(format!("Piece selected : {}", p.as_text()))),
                                Err(err) => Msg::SetDataFetchState(FetchState::Failed(err)),
                            }
                        });
                    }
                };

                info!("[Msg::GetData] Throw event Fetching");
                ctx.link()
                    .send_message(Msg::SetDataFetchState(FetchState::Fetching));
                false
            }
        }
    }
    fn view(&self, ctx: &Context<Self>) -> Html {
        match &self.markdown {
            FetchState::NotFetching => html! {
                <>
                    <button onclick={ctx.link().callback(|_| Msg::GetData(DataType::Markdown))}>
                        { "Get Markdown" }
                    </button>
                    <button onclick={ctx.link().callback(|_| Msg::GetData(DataType::AI))}>
                        { "Get AI thinking" }
                    </button>
                </>
            },
            FetchState::Fetching => html! { "Fetching" },
            FetchState::Success(data) => html! { markdown::render_markdown(data) },
            FetchState::Failed(err) => html! { err },
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, so when I click on the button "Get Markdown", my view displays "Fetching..." and when the JsFuture respond, the data is display on my web page.
My probem is with the "Get AI thinking", which is always freezing the page.

In my `ai_async_choose_piece_for_opponent()`, it seems the code `JsFuture::from(ai_promise).await?`is like throw as synchronous (even if in my logs, I notice that the `[Msg::GetData] Throw event Fetching` is throw without waiting the function's response).

The main difference between the two code is the fetch markdow call JsFuture with `JsFuture::from(window.fetch_with_request(&request)).await?`, seems like it's a javascript call, but how can I adapt my code to do that without calling an API ?

Thanks a lot for your help